# Weird int comparison bug in onContextItemSelected

Tags: java, android

I'm facing a weird bug in my onContextItemSelected event handler. Here is the code -

```
@Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle item selection
    int itemIntegerId = item.getItemId();
    if(itemIntegerId == 0)
    {           
        // Edit
        return true;            
    }
    else if(itemIntegerId == 1)
    {
        // Delete
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
 }
```

All this is placed inside a ListActivity class. The event is firing as it should, but even though the item with id 0 is selected,

```
    int itemIntegerId = item.getItemId();
    if(itemIntegerId == 0)
    {           
        // Edit
        return true;            
    }
```

**is failing**

I've spent over half hour trying to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated. I've attached *relevant images*.

[image: 0 == 0 Failing]
[image: else getting executed]

Comment: `item.getItemId();` is probably the cause, can we see some sources?

Comment: Could You attach relevant code? I mean full Activity code and menu xml if You are using one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you tell that it's failing? If it's just, that the debugger marks the last `return` of your method, that does not necessarily mean that that line is actually called.

Change your code to

```
if(itemIntegerId == 0)
{           
    // Edit
    Log.d("sometag", "Edit");
    return true;            
}
```

and see if 'Edit' gets logged -- or set a break point on the `Log.d` line and check if it is hit.

Comment: Okay I tried a combination of your suggestion, @Ridcully and @Jarvis, I declared constants at the top of my class and I'm comparing my id's to them. I also added a `Log.d` to the `if` statements and it does seem like they get called, but why do the `return` statements not run? Always the return statement in `else` gets called..

Comment: If `Edit` is logged, you can be sure, that the following `return true;` is executed as well. Add a `Log.d("sometag", "calling super");` before `return super.onContextItemSelected(item);` and I'd bet you a 1000$ that not both, the `Edit` and the `calling super` are logged for the same method call.

Comment: I'm not going to take that bet, I earn that much in two years! I'll try and let you know though.

Comment: I'm sorry it took me this long to try it, but you are right. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I too was more than once confused by this behaviour of the Eclipse Debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code for understand how to use contextuel menu:

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity{

    private final static int MENU_PARAMETRE = 1;
    private final static int MENU_QUITTER = 2;
    private final static int SOUSMENU_VIDEO = 11;
    private final static int SOUSMENU_AUDIO = 12;
    private final static int MENU_CONTEXT_1 = 13;
    private final static int MENU_CONTEXT_2 = 14;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewClick);
        registerForContextMenu(textView);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        SubMenu sousMenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, MENU_PARAMETRE, Menu.NONE, "Paramètres");
        sousMenu.setIcon(R.drawable.image1);
        sousMenu.add(0, SOUSMENU_AUDIO, Menu.NONE, "Audio");
        sousMenu.add(0, SOUSMENU_VIDEO, Menu.NONE, "Video");

        menu.add(0, MENU_QUITTER, Menu.NONE, "Quitter");

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){

        case MENU_PARAMETRE:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ouverture des paramètres", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case SOUSMENU_AUDIO:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ouverture des Audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case SOUSMENU_VIDEO:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ouverture des Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case MENU_QUITTER:
            this.finish();
            return true;

        default: return true;
        }

    }

    //on créé un menu contextuel sur la textview
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.textViewClick:
            {
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Menu Contextuel");
                menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.image1);
                menu.add(0, MENU_CONTEXT_1, 0, "Menu Contextuel 1");
                menu.add(0, MENU_CONTEXT_2, 0, "Menu Contextuel 2");
            }
            break;

        }
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    //On ajoute les actions sur les items du menu contextuel.
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){

        case MENU_CONTEXT_1:{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Contextuel 1 cliqué!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        case MENU_CONTEXT_2:{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Contextuel 2 cliqué!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewClick"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:textSize="30dip" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please convert the comments to english?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... why aren't you using the R.id_ constants to identify the context menu item? Resource IDs get regenerated every time a new resource is added, so the actual values can change.